# How to get align a form like table using div?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <label>Name</label><input type="text" id='name'/><br />
    <label>Email</label><input type="text" id='email'/><br />
    <label>Place</label><input type="text" id='place'/><br />
</div>
```

I'm new to CSS, I don't want  table to get aligned, but the perfection should be like same, and don't want to apply style to individual elements.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not use a table? A form like this is a prime example of the correct usage of a table.

Comment: Don't agree. Table is for tabular data. Form isn't one of.

Comment: Yep, I'm with Lex on this one - it might be easier to align, but it's a quick and dirty solution, one that just makes things difficult down the line. I'd suggest staying away from tables as far as possible :)

Comment: yea..table is enough,but its not working inside div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to align the labels and inputs next to one another, in which case you'll be needing floats. Here's the quick css code:

```
form {
 width: 500px;
 overflow:hidden;}

label {
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 40%;}

input {
 float: left;
 width: 55%;}
```

I think that should work :)

Comment: but..i'm trying to do it in jquery slidedown thing..for that it'not working..?

Comment: Could be any number of problems, HTML / CSS / jQuery. Will have to see the whole code before I can answer. I know this is a point a lot of people moan about, but it's relevant: make sure your HTML / CSS validates before moving onto jQuery - failing that, certain browsers might freak out. For instance, in the code you pasted in your question, you neglected to wrap it in <form></form> (at least from what I can see)... Things like that might affect jQuery plugins and functions.